# TabBar controls the NavigationBar

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

I added 2 ViewControllers into a TabBar, but now, the TabBar's NavigationBar 'took over' each view's NavigationBar.
I can't set a title for each one of them, I can't add buttons, nothing.
I tried a few solutions to solve it that I found on the internet, but nothing worked.
I need control over the NavigationBar of each one of the views, as I need them to be different, with different title, etc.
This is my TabBar code:

```
class TabBar: UITabBarController {
let homeVC = HomeVC()
let followingVC = FollowingVC()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.appColors.mainWhite]
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.appColors.mainWhite
    navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)

    homeVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .topRated, tag: 0)
    followingVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .contacts, tag: 1)

    let tabBarList = [homeVC, followingVC]
    viewControllers = tabBarList
}
}
```

I really need the option to configure each NavigationBar from it's own ViewController, or atleast from the TabBar class.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `UINavigationController` to each of your ViewControllers not your `UITabBarController`

First remove the UINavigationController of your `TabBar`, Either you have done this pragmatically or in the storyboard remove that first.

Second add `UINavigationController` to you ViewControllers

```
class TabBar: UITabBarController {

  let homeVC = HomeVC()
  let followingVC = FollowingVC()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    homeVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .topRated, tag: 0)
    followingVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .contacts, tag: 1)

    let homeNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeVC)
    let followingNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: followingVC)


    let tabBarList = [homeNavigationController, followingNavigationController]
    viewControllers = tabBarList
  }
}
```

Now if you change any properties like title and barButtons it will reflect accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, I tried but it didn't work. I tried hiddeing the Tabbar navigationbar, and configure each view controllers bar, but it won't work, and it stays exactly the same as before.

Comment: I am not suggesting to hide the Tabbar navigationbar remove it altogether.

Comment: How can I do that? I searched before trying to hide it but couldn't find.

Comment: @JohnDoah Are you initialising your `TabBar` programmatically of or form a story board? add the code to your question if programmatically.

Comment: programmatically, the only code of I have of the tabbar, is the one I posted. Is there another way to create a tabbar?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, the solution is:
The NavigationBar was not the TabBar navigation bar, but the screen that lead to the TabBar (Login Screen for example), I fixed it by hidding the navigation bar of the login screen when transfering to the TabBar controller, now the navigation bar of each view controller is shown and not blocked by the Login Viewcontrolelr navigationbar.